# Update query in yii2

Tags: yii2

I have a form where a user can enter different prices for products. The user can update prices too. The form looks like this:
[image]

I have two arrays, wherein one the `Id` is stored and in the other `Prices`.

So far, I have been able to reach this...

```
if(isset($_POST['addprice']))
{
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
    $price = $_REQUEST['price'];
    foreach ($price as $key => $val) {
        $priceds=$price[$key];
        $idds=$id[$key]; 
        if(!empty($priceds)){ 
            $command = $connection->createCommand('UPDATE businessitemots SET price='.$priceds.' WHERE id='.$idds.'');
            $command->execute();
        }
    }
    $this->redirect('index',[
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider
    ]);
}
```

My problem is that the values are not getting updated in the DB. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you in a transaction, and is it rolled back by default? Or does your statement yield an SQL error which isn't displayed by default? Check the PDO error mode settings.

Comment: Array of $key
(
    [0] => 39
    [1] => 56
    [2] => 70
    [3] => 73
    [4] => 74
    [5] => 75
    [6] => 76
    [7] => 77
)
Array of $price
(
    [0] => 100
    [1] => 200
    [2] => 300
    [3] => 100
    [4] => 200
    [5] => 300
    [6] => 100
    [7] => 200
)

Comment: Check if this `!empty($priceds)` returns true.

Comment: Also what is more important here, your query is vulnerable on SQL injection attack.

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Use prepared statements instead concating two strings!

Comment: Please show the code of the action and of the related  view.

Comment: Can you show your action full code?

Comment: Plus why use a framework if you're working around it completely? Might as well use plain `PDO`. You could use `ActiveRecord` or simply `createCommand()->update()` etc..

Comment: Try this `$connection->createCommand()->update( 'businessitemots', [ 'price' => $priceds ], 'id = '.$idds )->execute();`